# Getting the json object of a json object in python?

Tags: python, json

How can I get the json object that is inside another json?
I have an url that returns an json object (made in ruby) that contains another json object in one of the value, example:

```
json =
{"country":"canada", 
   "tours":"[
          {\"title\":\"Canadian Rockies Trail\",\"price\":\"$2249\"},
          {\"title\":\"2-Day Fantasy Island Getaway\",\"price\":\"$269\"}
            ]"}
```

Then, I want to get the object in the element of "tours" which is another json.

I have tried `json.load(json)['tours']` that provides me the data in "tours" but in **string** format so then, I can't manipulate the data. Is there any parse method to get this as a Json instead of string?

I would like to get the data as follow:

```
Canadian Rockies Trail ; price $2249

2-Day Fantasy Island Getaway; price $269
```

Comment: You say "made in ruby", so you're in a position to know something about how this JSON object is generated. Are you in a position to change the format of the JSON? Because this JSON makes no sense.

Comment: What you are calling a "JSON object" is just a string.  You can get that string and then parse it as JSON as you would with any other string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that I see here is that your `json['tours']` is a json encoded string. You should use `json.loads(str)` to turn that into a dictionary. I'd do this in-place and access it.

See code below

```
import json

foo ={"country":"canada", 
   "tours":"[{\"title\":\"Canadian Rockies Trail\",\"price\":\"$2249\"},{\"title\":\"2-Day Fantasy Island Getaway\",\"price\":\"$269\"}]"}

foo['tours'] = json.loads(foo['tours']) # turn tours into dict

for tour in foo['tours']:
    print "tour name : {} :::: tour price: {}".format(tour['title'],tour['price']) # tour is a dict now.
```

Comment: Yeah! that solve it! Thanks, it wasn't complicated but my mind was blocked xD

Comment: Happens. Glad you got it. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You should name your dict something other than json because it'll conflict with your import. Assuming it's called json_dict,

```
json.loads(json_dict['tours'])
```

should do it

Comment: The thing is when the first load is done, it returns a unicode object, not a json, getting the error: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: @JoseMendez I think you're confused about what a 'JSON object' is. It is just a string (possibly unicode). What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all the \" in your json.  Your json should look like.

```
j_dict = {"country": "canada",
          "tours": [{"title":"Canadian Rockies Trail","price":"$2249"},{"title":"2-Day Fantasy Island Getaway","price":"$269"}]}
```

then your program should look like the following.  First you need to convert your dictionary to a json string.

```
import json

j_string = json.dumps(j_dict)
foobar = json.loads(j_string)['tours']
```